# Creepers vs. Vines

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I see we have a [creepers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creepers) tag. Should this be a synonym of [vines](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vines)? Seems like it should be, but are there other kinds of creepers that are not vines or vice versa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All creepers are vines, but not all vines are creepers. My understanding is that [vines](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vines) generally refers to any plant that requires support.

- Some vines are active climbers and crawl up their supports, but do so without any assistance. i.e., they climb by twisting around their support or by sticking to the substrate (e.g., those that climb up walls).
- Other climbing vines send out tendrils/twines to cling on to supports (e.g., climbing beans).
- Some vines don't grow vigorously, but just require support to stay erect and bear fruit.
- [creepers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creepers) are those that grow horizontally and spread out on the ground, creating support for itself as it spreads by rooting its twines as necessary.

Coming to your question, I am not certain they should necessarily be synonyms, but they could be. I'd suggest for now that we use both [vines](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vines) and [creepers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creepers) if the question is about the latter, so as to make the distinction clear (just like [vegetables](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetables) and [root-vegetables](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/root-vegetables)).

Comment: Sounds good enough! I think I saw a creeper definition on Wikipedia that implied they were just vines - but it is the kind of definition where subtle changes could make a big difference. Eg. "mostly vines", "type of vine", or just "vines" would have very different meanings for us here.

Comment: Some creepers aren't vines. Dragons blood sedum, for example, is a mat of short, creeping stems that definitely creep but are obviously not vines.